# C# and iText7, set column width in absolute values

Tags: c#, pdf, itext7

I have to realize in c# with iText7 library something like this:

[image]

And I realized it, with the following code:

```
// doc is the document created in the Main function
public static void CreatePdf(Document doc) {
            // Initialize document
            Document document = doc;

            // a float array for columns width
            float[] colwidths = { 1, 3 };

            // creates table with a number of col equals to how many numbers are in float array
            Table table = new Table(UnitValue.CreatePercentArray(colwidths) );
            table.SetWidth(523);

            table.AddCell(new Cell(1,2).Add(new Paragraph("The table title goes here")));

            // creates a cell that is 3rows and 1col large; vertically centers the text
            table.AddCell(new Cell(3, 1).Add(new Paragraph("here goes the Text1"))
                 .SetVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE) );

            // adds 3 rows in the 2nd column
            table.AddCell("row 1");
            table.AddCell("row 2");
            table.AddCell("row 3");

            document.Add(table);
            document.Close();
        }
```

This way I decided that the second column is 3 times wide the first.

But I want to do this with absolute values, so I can add columns and rows with more precision, I.E. I know that the total width is 523 points, so I want the first column to be 123points wide, the second one 400 points wide.

- How can I do that?
- If I put the first column 100points wide and the second 300points wide, does it leave blank space on the right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Table` has a constructor that accepts `float[]` where you can specify column widths in points:

```
Table table = new Table(new float[] { 123, 400 });
```

The resulting table width will be the sum of the columns provided, unless you explicitly set the width (using `SetWidth`), in which case each column is resized proportionately.

For example, if you called:

```
table.SetWidth(1046);
```

The resulting column widths would be doubled to 226 points and 800 points respectively.

Comment: Ahh thanks!! Now I get it... Just another question, how much is a Point? Since I have to set a length in centimeters

Comment: Ok, I found a millimetersToPoint() function, but It does not do the job perfectly. I ended up editing manually the size until it fits to what I need. However I post the function here, for the people who could need it: 

`private static float MillimetersToPoints(float value) {

            return (value / 25.4f) * 72f;

        }`